# normal distribution; iron python

Tags: python, random, ironpython, normal-distribution

I want the user to specify a range delta, sigma for the spread and the number of random values it should produce.
But what's the best way in Iron Python to produce random values with a normal distributon? I found a function in NumPy that does that, but to my understanding it doesn't work with Iron Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `random` module has a function that will do this for you: `random.gauss(mu, sigma)` (or `random.normalvariate(mu, sigma)`, although the former is supposedly slightly faster according to the docs). See also the IronPython docs [here](https://ironpython-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/library/random.html).

Comment: (+1) Might be worth mentioning `random.normalvariate()` for completeness.